# How to reserve first 32 hosts in IP address range

Tags: networking, cidr

I am using NoDogSplash which is a captive portal, meaning it redirects your packets and forces you to authenticate before you can access the Internet. It does this in an isolated 10.0.0.0 network. Now, I would like to make it so that the first X addresses (let's say 32) are not managed by NoDogSplash at all, so I can put my access points and some other computers in that range.

There is a parameter called GatewayIPRange in the configuration that seems to do what I want, but I don't know what I should set it to.

> By setting this parameter, you can specify a range of IP addresses
>   on the GatewayInterface that will be responded to and managed by
>   Nodogsplash.  Addresses outside this range do not have their packets
>   touched by Nodogsplash at all.
>   Defaults to 0.0.0.0/0, that is, all addresses.

I know that by changing the network mask I can split a big network into smaller subnets, but as I want all hosts to have the same gateway (namely, the router the captive portal is running in), I don't think I can do this.

If at all possible, please provide a solution for the general case and/or lots of background info (or links to it, as I know this is a very elementary question).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

At best you're going to be able to exclude half the addresses, this is subnetting but it isn't actually going to divide the network, it is just going to create a list of IPs that will either match or do not match.

I think that if you want certain machines and APs to not be managed,  the `TrustedMACList` option is going to be better, and although MAC addresses are spoofable, the same thing applies to ranges of IPs.

> Parameter: TrustedMACList
>    Default: none
>
> Comma-separated list of MAC addresses who are not subject to
>   authentication, and are not restricted by any FirewallRuleSet.
>   N.B.: weak security, since MAC addresses are easy to spoof.
>
> TrustedMACList 00:00:CA:FE:BA:BE, 00:00:C0:01:D0:0D

Answer (score 0):

It appears they are using CIDR notation for specifying the range of addresses to set `GatewayIPRange` to.  This is quite valid.

Just because this notation can also be used to specify a subnet doesn't mean it is always used for this.  It is also used in routing tables, ACLs and other places where it doesn't necessarily imply a subnet (but might).  It's use is more flexible than that!

[Read up more on CIDR notation here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)